# Make a Secure PhoneGap/Cordova App (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, security, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a new app for android. I tested PhoneGap the last days and I think it is a very good platform to develop an app.
I started developing and now I have some security concerns.

**Online**

All the JavaScript gets hosted on my server and the app needs them to start.

**Offline**

I have my JavaScript in the app and it just validates some files before startup.

*I want that my app is working online and offline.*

---

**Problem**

If the files are offline every user (with root) can edit the code. The user can remove for example the In-App Purchase and the file validation for the offline mode.

I searched through the internet and I need so say that I didn't found a good answer how to secure my app.

**I hope here is somebody who can give me tips or ideas to make my app working online and offline with beeing secure. Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no bulletproof solution to make hybrid apps secure, however you could obfuscate your code using tools like https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS. Although not safe from reverse engineering, uglification willl make more difficulty to modify the code.